# IIS config ssl over local network

Tags: ssl, iis, https, lan, self-signed

I'm currently having in my LAN an IIS server that I used to access with my browser by it IP (HTTP requests), and now I want to config it so I will be able to access it using https instead.

I created a `self-signed certificate` (in IIS manager) and I added a new binding pointing to the https address, then I exported the cer and installed it on my computer.

But when I tried to access it using my browser ("~https://192.168.0.213"), it pops up an "unsafe" message and then showed this screen:

[image]

What should I do in order to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Clearly it says what 403.7 means.

Comment: @LexLi  can you direct me?, how can I config this?